# Is there any explanation for a near-death experience?

Tags: medical-science, biology, physiology, religion, near-death-experience

One idea I used to hear a lot about was that when people are near-death and saved by medical science that they sometimes see "a light at the end of a tunnel" in a vision.

Today I read about an article about a new best-seller from an ambitious 4-year-old in [Nebraska](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebraska):

['I met great granddad...and he had wings': Boy who 'went to heaven' is now best selling author](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1368467/I-met-granddad--wings-Colton-Burpo-went-heaven-speaks-relatives-book-Heaven-For-Real.html).

Here's his [#1 New York Times Bestselling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Times_Bestseller) book ["Heaven is for Real" on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0849946158):

[image]

The only problem is that I remember [seeing shows on TV](http://www.near-death.com/tv.html) that suggest [near-death experiences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_death) can be repeated in a [controlled environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-G_training).

Is there any evidence to suggest that near-death experiences and "the light at the end of the tunnel" have a scientific explanation?

Comment: I'll just add this, from a personal point of view (since it happened to me). There were no "drugs" and no sport/ situation before hand. What I was able to notice was that the loss of vision (after the heart stopped) start at the periphery of the eye, and vision diminished until only the "white light", which in truth was the environmental light (in my case the sun) before blacking out completely. Think of it as when you look a light for a few second than instantly close your eye: it's the same phenomenon but inversed. I do hope that help anyone interested in this subject. Something like this th

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There is ample scientific explanations for the physiological reactions that people experience.  From [PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2156135) (my emphasis):

> The Near-Death Experience (NDE) is a dissociative mental state with characteristic features. **These can be reproduced** by ketamine which acts at sigma sites and blocks N-methyl-D-aspartate (NMDA) linked phencyclidine (PCP) receptors to reduce ischaemic damage. Endogenous ligands, alpha and beta-endopsychosin, have been detected for these receptors which suggests an explanation for some NDE's: the endopsychosins may be released in abnormal quantity to protect neurons from ischaemic and other excitotoxic damage, and the NDE is a side effect on consciousness with important psychological functions.

The light in the [tunnel effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_vision) is an easy one, since I have personally experienced it numerous times in a high-G environment.  Your eyes naturally create a tunnel effect as they start to lose oxygen.

As for seeing loved ones, in the case of this particular book, that is more likely a [post hoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc) occurrence for financial gain as well as societally influenced expectations.  The personal history and background of the boy Colton, and the author Todd Burpo, align exactly with what they wrote about (isn't it funny that no one ever experiences a "vision" that would be opposed to their expectations and personal history, like a christian seeing Vishnu for instance?).

And it is established that autobiographical [memories can be implanted in individuals](http://www.nspb.net/index.php/nspb/article/view/59/54), and that [children are especially susceptible](http://users.owt.com/crook/memory/) to this.

> Loftus (1997) investigated memory distortion and the relation with the degree of confidence in the existence of a false memory. She calls this phenomenon the "misinformation effect". She observed that if witnesses of an event are later exposed to new and misleading information about it, their recollections become distorted (Loftus, 1997). Loftus was able to empirically demonstrate this phenomenon with autobiographical memories. With corroboration from the participants' family members, Loftus was relatively successful at implanting false autobiographical memories.

**EDIT TO ADD**:  [I just found this article today that is relevant to this answer](http://whyevolutionistrue.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/why-out-of-body-and-near-death-experiences-dont-prove-god/).

> This week, in “[The neurology of near-death experiences](http://www.happinessinthisworld.com/2011/05/15/the-neurology-of-near-death-experiences/#more-7165)“, Alex debunks the religious trappings that attach to the “out-of-body” and similar experiences that occur in conjunction with operations and medical episodes.  In particular, he shows that experiences such as dreamlike states, tunnel vision, and leaving and returning to one’s body are all phenomena that have well-understood medical causes.  Some of them can even be reproduced by stimulating people’s brains.

I suggest anyone interested in the subject check out the links.

Comment: "...since I have personally experienced it numerous times in a high-G environment" <- awesome.

Comment: Video of it is disturbing.  When you wake up grom G-LOC, the whole "funky chicken" is totally beyond recall, but I do recall the tunnel and grey out effect.  Our bodies do all sorts of weird things!  Don't even get me started on sleep paralysis and a whole host of other things our bodies do that the average layperson is totally unaware of.

Comment: Forgot to put the link in there first time around talking about the physiology of tunnel vision...  It's there now, although a Wiki-link...  My google-fu isn't the best.

Comment: @Larian LeQuella as you mentioned sleep paralysis, may be you have comment on this: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/183/false-awakening-or-similar-phenomenon

Comment: Egle, the two answers combined pretty much summed up what I would have brought to the table.

Comment: @Larian, do you have any citations for "that is more likely a post hoc occurrence for financial gain as well as societally influence expectations"?

Comment: As I said, "more likely".  All evidence suggest the visions aligned perfectly with the expectations of the 4 year old child and stories he had been told, and the personal outlook of the ghost writer who has made no secret of his belief in a European, blonde, blue eyed jesus figure.

Comment: Ah. Sorry, I interpreted that part of the answer to be addressing the title question in general, when (based on your comment) I believe you're actually addressing the boy and the book specifically. Correct me if I'm wrong. I suppose the original question given is somewhat ambiguous about whether on NDE in general, the book, or both. If you could edit your last sentence to indicate you're addressing the book specifically I'll +1.

Comment: Done DuckMaestro, with additional back up of the phenomenon that I am sure the now 11 year old boy is repeating.

Comment: Voted back up! Thx

Comment: @LarianLeQuella I read both links about implanting false memories, and I don't believe either are pertinent to the question (which doesn't take away from the rest of your excellent answer). Unless I am misreading, the second link details how the study (about children) was *unscientific and had factual errors*. The first link described a scientific study (about adults), but its results — adults claiming to remember fictional events, and confessing to mistakes they didn't make — doesn't seem related to NDEs.

Comment: @ClosureCowboy, the relevance of those things is that people will remember (and see) the things that they have had exposure to in their lives.  You don't hear about a Baptist ever seeing Vishnu, or a Muslim seeing the virgin Mary.  So white the tie in isn't rock solid, it gets to the way a brain works.  And in this particular case of the little boy, I think it's relevant because of what he thinks he saw and the expectations of what was written.  In other words, he probably didn't see a thing, and then his parents (or the author) reminded him what he DID see.

Comment: I dislike the Australian billionaire Kerry Packer, but I respect what he had to say about the "light at the end of the tunnel": after being clinically dead for eight minutes following his first heart attack, he said "I've been on the other side and let me tell you, son, there's fucking nothing there."

Comment: Interesting theory regarding dissociated states. One thing this doesn't explain is the "flashes before eyes"... visual hallucinations are sparse when the PCP receptors are affected. Visual hallucinations certainly are highly reported with NDE and your reasoning for it not to be isn't sufficient in this respect.

Comment: @rickyduck I must admit some ignorance in terms of the accepted explanation on this (if there is one).  Although, what I know of physiology, and have experienced myself from coming back from G-LOC, when blood suddenly rushes back to the brain and eyes, there are all sorts of interesting visual phenomenon.  Flashing lights being one.  Also, a common medical practice is to shine a light into a patient's eyes to judge levels of consciousness, it's just as likely they are disoriented enough not to understand the sensory inputs, and thus attribute it to an expectation.

Comment: @LarianLeQuella As an aside I have heard anecdotal accounts of a Muslim seeing Mary, a Hindu seeing Jesus, and a Siberian shaman seeing Yahweh. Not that I believe those accounts necessarily occurred as reported, but they are interesting nevertheless. The Muslim, Hindu, and the Siberian shaman were all aware of those figures already. I have only heard one case of someone unaware of a particular religious figure reportedly having witnessed a vision of them--and that story comes from Africa and is shaky at best, fabricated at worst.

Answer (score 9):

There is a fairly comprehensive article on the topic at

[Near-death experience (NDE) - The Skeptic's Dictionary - Skepdic.com](http://www.skepdic.com/nde.html)

Some details from one study:

> Blackmore attributes the feelings of extreme peacefulness of the NDE to the release of endorphins in response to the extreme stress of the situation. The buzzing or ringing sound is attributed to cerebral anoxia and consequent effects upon the connections between brain cells (op. cit., 64).

Answer (score 5):

One popular explanation is that near-death experiences are due to [Dimethyltryptamine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimethyltryptamine) (DMT), a psychedelic drug produced natually, in small amounts, in the brain.  It is speculated that large amounts of DMT are released during near-death experiences, though I don't know of any studies that confirm this.

> Dr. Rick Strassman, while conducting DMT research in the 1990s at the University of New Mexico, advanced the hypothesis that a massive release of DMT from the pineal gland prior to death or near death was the cause of the near death experience (NDE) phenomenon. Several of his test subjects reported NDE-like audio or visual hallucinations.

Interestingly enough, this brain-chemical is also hypothesized to be the cause of alien abductions:

> Several subjects also reported contact with 'other beings', alien like, insectoid or reptilian in nature, in highly advanced technological environments where the subjects were 'carried', 'probed', 'tested', 'manipulated', 'dismembered', 'taught', 'loved' and even 'raped' by these beings

Comment: This answer itself is HIGHLY skeptical. There's no proof that the pineal glan produces DMT. However, the pineal gland does produce melatonin (our "sleep" drug), which is structurally similar. furthermore the "building blocks" to creat dimethyltryptamine all exist within the pineal, and many theory as to why the pineal is positioned where it is, and its overactive security mechanism are intriguing and may point to DMT production in high stress situations (birth, death and NDE)

Comment: @rickyduck There was a [2013 publication](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bmc.2981/abstract;jsessionid=ABB320FE8927B6DB609105D707440624.f04t04) that found DMT in rat pineal glands via LC/MS/MS so there is no reason to be skeptical of the production of DMT in and of itself. The "why" aspect is highly speculative though.

Answer (score 2):

I have a bucket of random thoughts to this.

Two months ago, I saw two [broadcasts in the Swiss TV, LANG=de_CH](http://www.sendungen.sf.tv/sternstunden/Nachrichten/Archiv/2011/02/07/sternstundeneinzel/Sternstunde-Religion-vom-13.-Februar-20112) about near-death experiences, the first being a kind of report, and the second a talk. The first of the videos isn't available anymore (only to buy on DVD/VHS) and few wordings and a link to literature remains. I can try to give a brief conclusion.

At most, the broadcasting station, which is a federal, not a private station, is serious, tends to higher culture and quality, but when it comes to religion - well... . Now the Swiss is, afaik, mostly protestantism, at least the German speaking part of it; two of the first popular heretics origins from the Swiss, Zwingli and Calvin. But not all of the religious people believe in near-death experiences. My impression was, that the report couldn't decide, whether to support the claims of NDE or not. They hadn't much material, some witnesses from hearsay, and hadn't much against, but mixed it - for my feelings just to keep the interest high. If you debunk such a claim in the first minutes you can stop the video after 5 Minutes. After the report, there was a talk which is today still available, but might vanish in near future: [Talk with Judith Hardegger and sociologist of religion, Hubert Knoblauch](http://www.videoportal.sf.tv/video?id=eee95278-f812-4cfb-9bf5-d3f15507ab34), again, language de_CH., duration about 30 min.

I don't remember much from the video. People, talking about a tunnel with light, of cause. And an experiment, but which was planned, at least not yet finished: Since people often experience such NDE when being in a surgery, and often claim, that they leave their body (out-of-body experience, OOBE) and floating at the top of the room, looking down towards their body, the experimenter placed some kind of beamer at the top, which displayed simple figures in a random way, so that they could only be seen from above, and that the doctor and other people wouldn't know what was displayed, but a floating ghost would be able to see them. Or not. Which would show, that they weren't really out of body, floating around.

Now I try to summarize the talk. It is a different video, but the scientist had just seen the other video. 
It's not my opinion, which I report, but the opinion of the sociologist, which I try to repeat in condensed form:

- His viewpoint is not natural sciences, but sociological, psychological. He is interested in what the people think it is, how they feel, and how deeply impressed they are.
- since 60 years there are studies going on (in the Swiss, and nearby, in Freiburg/Germany), but without much[sic!] evidence.
- Whether the people are dead or not is normally not clear. Death by heart is the normal criteria, rarely: by brain.
- The experience of time does not fit to the experience of time for people awake (Doctores), but is more like in a dream. A long journey in a dream may only last a few minutes in real sleep.
- Not everybody who was declared to be death, but 'came back' has NDE, and not everybody who has NDE was clinicly death.
- Nearly 1/3 of the experiences isn't about light and wonderful feelings (2/3), but about pain and horror.
- People in the western world 'experience' to fly to heaven, while people in China tend to move into the earth, which is congruent to the culture, which surrounds the people.
- People today in the swiss 'meat' relatives during their NDE, like mother, grandmother and so on. A farmer in the 13th century meats his whole village and Karl der Große. Friar in the 8 Century meet their whole cloister. This reflects pretty much the trend to individualism during that time in our culture.
  Former experiences talk about an old, wise man - today, people experience a white light. The stories are getting more abstract.
- he becomes a bit angry about the question, whether this isn't prove, that all this is hallucination. I couldn't follow  how he countered that.
- He emphasized, that in contrast to religious believes, there is a continuation of identity and a continuation of feelings, of felt body awareness.
- most western people today don't connect their experience with religion, but mystic and transcendence.
- There are comparing studies of West- and East-Germany. More bad experiences in the former DDR (socialistic, atheistic staate), but not comparable to the pictures from hell, which where often found in the US.
- He would like to do much more research, but would need money to do so.

There were more arguments made, so if you speak german, watch the video and correct or complete me.

In sum, it was a differentiated view on the facts, and afaik a honest presentation of the known facts, as far as he knows them. Weak, in the absence of natural science, but aware of this weakness.

One thing bothered me often: The acceptance of the term NDE. The people did not die. They survived, and their living went on. So why name it 'near death'? He is on the one hand aware of this fact, and tells it that way himself, but few sentences later he says, that, while it isn't objectively near death, the people experience it as such. But since no living being had experienced the death nobody can, not even subjectively, claim to have knowledge, how close to a real death experience it is. It's just a projection, an illusion. But I guess that's the strength of the talk: While this person has a different opinion about the conclusions of the facts, he doesn't mud the water but is a reliable source of his observations.